# How can I change the default object value for lm()?

Tags: r

Apologies for any grammar issues as English is not my first language.

I am trying to investigate data in regards to whether black people are discriminated against in comparison to white people when submitting their resumes (Bertrand and Mullainathan, 2004).

I do the following:

```
> resume <- read.csv("resume.csv", header=T)
> fit <- lm(call~race, data=resume)
> summary(fit1)

Call:
lm(formula = call ~ race, data = resume)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.09651 -0.09651 -0.06448 -0.06448  0.93552 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.064476   0.005505  11.713  < 2e-16 ***
racewhite   0.032033   0.007785   4.115 3.94e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2716 on 4868 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.003466,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.003261 
F-statistic: 16.93 on 1 and 4868 DF,  p-value: 3.941e-05
```

As you can see from the summary, it displays 'racewhite' as the variable and I have no idea how to change this so it instead displays 'raceblack'.

I know this might be quite a simple question, but thank you in advance for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

`lm`  appears to be treating `race` as a factor.  By default, the first level of the factor is used as a control and coefficients for the other levels represent differences between the given level and the control.  The "first" level of a factor defined by character values is the first level when the levels are sorted alphabetically.

You can change this by using `reorder` before the call to `lm`.  Or, assuming `race` has only two levels, you can simply reinterpret the coefficient by changing it's sign: based on the results above, the coefficient for `race` regarding `white` as control will be `-0.032033`.  All other statistics - std err, p-value etc will be unchanged.

It would have been helpful to see at least some of your input data.